# get hyperlink from ODS file in python?

Tags: python, ods, pyexcel

I need to parse an ODS spreadsheet in Python.  No big deal, I can do this:

```
import pyexcel
book = pyexcel.get_book(file_name="/path/to/my/file.ods")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in sheet:
   print row
```

Here's the rub.  One of the columns contains hyperlinks.  In LibreOffice, the cells display as "Bob", "Dick", "Hal", with http://example.com/robert.html, http://example.com/richard.html and http://example.com/harold.html as the underlying links, respectively.

I want the values of the links, but referring to `row[0]` gives me the display values, not the underlying values.

Is there a feature in pyexcel that I can use to get at those links?

EDIT:  per request,  you can find the file at https://www.government.nl/binaries/government/documents/reports/2016/01/15/national-terrorism-list/eng-terrorismelijst.ods

Comment: Can you provide a demo of  `file.ods`? It may help us to solve the problem.